# Two questions about app widget with collection

Tags: android, android-widget, android-appwidget

Currently I am studying the app widget with collection, and there are two points I am confused, see below codes

onUpdate codes

```
        Intent serviceIntent=new Intent(context,StackService.class);
        serviceIntent.setData(Uri.parse(serviceIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        RemoteViews remoteViews=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.stack_widget);
        remoteViews.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.stack_widget,serviceIntent);
        remoteViews.setEmptyView(R.id.stack_widget,R.id.stack_empty);

        Intent toastIntent = new Intent(context, StackWidget.class);
        toastIntent.setAction(StackWidget.TOAST_ACTION);
        toastIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetIds[i]);
        PendingIntent toastPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, toastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        remoteViews.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.stack_widget, toastPendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i],remoteViews);
```

getViewAt codes

```
public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews=new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.stack_item);
        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.item_image,R.raw.logo);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.item_text,list.get(position));

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putInt(StackWidget.EXTRA_ITEM, position);

        Intent fillIntent=new Intent();
        fillIntent.putExtras(extras);

        remoteViews.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.item_button,fillIntent);
        return remoteViews;
    }
```

First question is what purpose of below code,
**serviceIntent.setData(Uri.parse(serviceIntent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));**
I read through google api doc, but can't find answer.

Second question is about toastIntent, why intent action is being set at onUpdate method rather than at getViewAt method? And why pending intent that has a custom action called TOAST_ACTION will be fired when button being pressed?

Thanks for answering my questions in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`Intent.toUri()` can convert this `Intent` into a `String` holding a URI representation of it.

`setDate` often used in an undeclared `Intent`, which can start a component related to the date.

Comment: Could you explain to me the purpose of putting setData here?

Comment: No,I will not tell you.